# scp command line task in gradle

Tags: gradle

I would like to use 'scp' as command-line command task in gradle to copy files to a server. I got stock at error:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not find property 'Scp' on root project
```

I am thinking i need to import 'scp' into my gradle build project, but how do i search and locate appropriate plugins in gradle (in our case, for 'scp')? Here is the build.gradle so far:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.eriwen:gradle-js-plugin:1.5.0'
    }
}
// Invoke the plugin
apply plugin: 'js'
apply plugin:'base'

...

minifyJs {
    source = jsDev
    dest = file("${projectDir}/public/build/${appName}-min.js")
    closure {
        warningLevel = 'QUIET'
    }
}


task uploadJs( type: Scp) {
    source = minifyJs
    host = 'domain.com:/path-to-repo'
    userName = 'username'
    password = 'password'
}
```

Any assistance on how to make the task - 'uploadJs' to work is much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no gradle task of type Scp, which is why you are getting that error. You want the [ant scp task.](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html) You can translate ant tasks into gradle in a standard way [as described here.](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/ant.html)